# How can I add a dynamic numer of UserControls in an asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here's the problem:

I have an (almost) empty aspx page and I want to insert a certain number of the same user control in this page.

The fact is that I don't know how many of them I will need.

I tried to add them from the CodeBehind but it seems that the UserControls are completely empty.

In the main page (MainDiv is a div with runat="server"):

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebUserControl1 uc = new WebUserControl1();
    WebUserControl1 uc1 = new WebUserControl1();
    MainDiv.Controls.Add(uc);
    MainDiv.Controls.Add(uc1);
}
```

(it doesn't work if i put this code on Page_Init, Page_Load or Page_PreRender)

UserControl (gw is a Gridview contained in the UserControl):

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_data != null)
    {
        gw.DataSource = _data;
        gw.DataBind();
    }
}
```

when I arrive there, gw is null (this.Controls.Count is 0).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the [repeater control](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/asp-net-repeater-control) is for.

Comment: **Snap!** :-P Nice post David